# How to prevent remote login for SYS

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Is it possible to prevent the remote logins for the SYS user? Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 7):

Set the system parameter

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET remote_login_passwordfile = NONE SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

Then restart the database.